# When to use --socket-exists with iptables?

Tags: iptables

I'm learning iptables and I have a hard time understanding when to use the "--socket-exists" option of the "owner" matcher. Could you explain what is the practical benefit of this option (with an example, if possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `--socket-exists` to determine that a packet originated locally on the system, where outgoing packets are associated with a socket, instead of a forwarded packet that originated from another system, which has no associated socket.